# How to use document.onload Properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently learning `window.onload` and `document.onload` as attributes on html. But i fail to use them properly. In my code i want to focus a specific text area named "emri", using the `document.onload` but without success. Some would say to use it as a script or smth, but i want to use it as an attribute inside the tag. What am i doing wrong?

```
 <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
  shrink-to-fit=no">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">


   </head>

   <body onload="document.my-form1.emri.focus();" >

  <main class="my-form">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-flex-start">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Apliko</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form name="my-form1" onsubmit=" return formValidation();">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="emri" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Emri juaj:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="emri">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Try with <body onLoad="document.getElementById('emri').focus();">

Answer (score 1):

Here your updated html :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
  shrink-to-fit=no">


<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css"
 integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
 crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body onload="document.getElementById('emri').focus();">
 <main class="my-form">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-flex-start">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">Apliko</div>
     <div class="card-body">
      <form name="my-form1" onsubmit=" return formValidation();">
       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="emri" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Emri
         juaj:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emri" id="emri"/>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `autofocus` attribute to the input.

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="emri" autofocus>
```

Comment: If he is using HTML5

Comment: also he will need to add `id` to input so `<body onLoad="document.getElementById('emri').focus();">` to work. @GovindParashar

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong how you use `window.onload´. It is the name of the form. Since there is a "-" character in the name, you should use it like this:

```html
<body onload="document['my-form1'].elements.emri.focus();">
```

see: [Example](https://just-run.it/ryBaiQTp4/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select like this

```html
<body onload="document.getElementsByName('emri')[0].focus();">
```

If you are using HTML5, you can use like `autofocus` attribute in `input`.